# Utilizar checkbox para fazer surgir imagem

Tags: html, css

Boa noite, sou bem iniciante em desenvolvimento web, gostaria de uma ajuda, quero fazer 2 checkbox, no qual, quando o primeiro é marcado, aparece a imagem1 , e quando o segundo for marcado, aparecer a imagem2.

Comment: Bem vindo Arthur, sua pergunta está muito ampla e está faltando informações, antes de fazer uma pergunta dê uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Com base nas informações desse link você pode editá-la, adicionar seu código e melhorá-la.

Comment: Sem código, tudo que vc vai conseguir são exemplos baseados em..... _nada_. Tudo depende do seu layout, porque talvez (provavelmente) necessite até de JavaScript para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara basicamente vc precisa usar a *pseudo-classe* `:checked` do `input` e o seletor adjacente `+` para quando marcar o *checkbox* mostrar a imagem que vem a seguir.

Aqui tem um exemplo bem básico, usei o minimo de CSS e HTML, para vc perceber melhor como funciona a dinâmica do `input:checked + img` *(o + faz com que o input checado pegue só a imagem que vem a seguir)*

```css
img {
    display: none;
}
input:checked + img {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">1
<img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">2
<img src="https://placecage.com/101/101">
```

Aqui vc pode ler sobre as *pseudo-classes*: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre os *Seletores* CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletores_CSS

Comment: desculpe o modo de fazer a pergunta, sei que foi bem genérico, porém, o que eu queria era realmente isso que vc fez, mt obrigado msm.

Comment: @arthur essa base de CSS pode te ajudar de muitas formas, inclusive para fazer menus escondidos, collapses e acordeons, até slider da para fazer. Se vc acha que resolveu a pergunta, lembre-se de marcar o ícone ✔  abaixo das setinhas da minha resposta ;)